# Hibernate validator show custom element name in message

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

I'm using Hibernate validation in my Spring webapp. I currently have everything configured as completely default, and I have created a ValidationMessage.properties file that I intend to fill with custom messages.

For all my Google-ing, I can't find the answer to what I believe should be a fairly simple question - what is the best way to get a nicely printed element name alongside the error text?

For example, for the below messages, I would want it to say "Old password cannot be empty" and "New Password cannot be empty"

```
<form:input path="oldPassword"/>
<form:input path="newPassword"/>
```

Is it possible to add my own attributes to the `@NotEmpty` annotation and then refer to them in my custom message?

```
@NotEmpty(nicename="Old Password")
private String oldPassword;

@NotEmpty(nicename="New Password")
private String newPassword;
```

And then in the properties file just refer to it like this -

```
org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message=${nicename} cannot be empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it other way around, so

```
@NotEmpty(message="{nicename} cannot be empty")
```

And add a property with a *nicename* key in ValidationMessages. By the way, a great article about using the custom messaging in spring. It doesn't discuss your particular case, but surely helpful

http://www.silverbaytech.com/2013/04/16/custom-messages-in-spring-validation/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem I see with this though, is that if I want to change the "cannot be empty" part of the message for 100 elements, I need to change the message attribute for all 100 of those elements. If it was possible to do it in the way I hoped, with the message specified in the properties file and then injecting a referenced "nicename" attribute, that would be easier. A change to the default message would only require editing one line in the properties file, instead of changing all the message attributes in the java source files.